# Looping over JSON - Require Logic to count the sum of values

Tags: python, json, algorithm, typescript, logic

I'm trying to get sum of values of key `number` from the below JSON.

sum = 193(21+52+52+68)

I will be using loops over here instead accessing directly - response['jobs']['0']['lastBuild']['number'].
Can anyone please provide the logic? any programming language would be fine.

```
{
"_class": "hudson.model.Hudson",
"jobs": [
    {
        "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
        "name": "ADP-CHINA-IT",
        "lastBuild": {
            "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
            "number": 21
        }
    },
    {
            "_class": "com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder",
            "name": "A",
            "jobs": [
                {
                    "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
                    "name": "dummy",
                    "lastBuild": {
                        "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
                        "number": 52
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_class": "com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder",
                    "name": "F",
                    "jobs": [
                        {
                            "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
                            "name": "pipeline",
                            "lastBuild": {
                                "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
                                "number": 52
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
            "name": "CICD_Windows_Shared_Lib_Test",
            "lastBuild": {
                "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
                "number": 68
            }
        }


]
```

}

Comment: This seems like the structured output corresponding to a folder hierarchy. Does that mean that the `number` key can be nested at any level?

Comment: @DroidX86 yes, the number key can be nested at any level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python:

```
def sum_(s, dict_):
    return s + reduce(sum_, dict_.get("jobs", []), 0) + dict_.get("lastBuild", {}).get("number", 0)


reduce(sum_, response["jobs"], 0)
```

Comment: function `reduce` from `functools`

Comment: Can we have the same logic in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce` recursively:

```
type Job = {lastBuild: {number: number}, jobs?: Job[]}

const reduction = (acc: number, job:Job) => acc + job.lastBuild.number 
      + (job.jobs ? job.jobs.reduce(reduction,0) : 0); // recursion

response.jobs.reduce(reduction, 0);
```